# Resource in layout xml but compiler error with "not found"

Tags: java, android, resources

I have had some success with trying to get a sound synthesizer app to work. It worked fine on simulator, but always crash on the 8th time on my mobile phone (*OS 7.0*, simulator *OS 6.0*, *API level 21*, or *OS 5.0*). The error message was convoluted. I only remember the red-highlighted lines with *`"AudioFlinger"`*, and an error code with *`"AudioTrack"`* and *`"-20"`*.

I saw some advices here about changing the API level of the app to 21, but Android Studio only did 22, so that was what I changed. And that corrupted the whole thing. I am getting *`AAPT`* error on compile. The thing will not even start the emulator for try-run.

So I scrapped the whole thing, copy out the source codes (and layouts and other resources) and started a new project fresh, and copied back these files.

Now again, there is a compile error. There are multiple objects on XML that the Java source code reference to. All those lines with `R.id.textview`. All the *`"R"`* are now red with error, with the error message,

error: ***resource style/Base.V26.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar not found.***

This seems to be something completely "background" issue that I have no idea how to resolve, nor can I find solutions here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers. But clean and rebuild did not work. This is the auto-generated code: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     And the "R" is still red (error). Sorry I can't format codes here.

Answer (score 0):

This can cause trouble when there is a need to make new files, so clearing 'caches will clear the oldcache` and make Android Studio faster.
Going to Build > Clean Project

Answer (score 0):

clean your project or rebuild and start android studio again

Comment: Thanks for the answers, all! I found that starting new project on Android Studio will also get this strange error. So I had to try the ultimate "fix" - complete uninstall of the program, wipe all configuration (thanks to another help from StackOverflow), and do a clean install. Now things are working fine, and I am back to fixing the "AudioFlinger cannot create, error -12" error.